# Pinnable taskpane versionOverride 1.0; pin not there when deployed

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'm attempting to add a pinnable taskpane to my existing app.

per the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/xml-manifest-overview?tabs=tabid-1)
I've added versionOverride 1.1 within versionOverride 1.0,

Copy and pasted version override into itself and updated with proper version override opening tag,

Added supports pinning true to taskpane action in VO1.1,

the pin appears when sideloading the local repo but there is no pin when deployed.

Here is my manifest for reference:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0" xsi:type="MailApp">
  <Id>xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxx</Id>
  <Version>1.0.1.1</Version>
  <ProviderName>Alphy Co</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Reflect AI"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="Reflect AI gives you feedback to ensure your message is as risk-free and respectful as possible - before hitting send."/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/Alphy_Icon_512x512.png"/>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/Alphy_Icon_512x512.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://www.alphyco.com/support"/>
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://www.alphyco.com</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox"/>
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1"/>
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>

  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
  <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Edit"/>
  <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Edit"/>
</Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox"/>
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url"/>
 
          <!-- Message Compose -->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <Group id="msgComposeCmdGroup">
                <Label resid="GroupLabel"/>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgComposeInsertGist">
                  <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Title"/>
                    <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
                
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>

       <bt:Images>
    <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/Alphy_Icon_64x64.png"/>
    <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/Alphy_Icon_64x64.png"/>
    <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/Alphy_Icon_64x64.png"/>
  </bt:Images>
  <bt:Urls>
    <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html"/>
    <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
  </bt:Urls>
  <bt:ShortStrings>
    <bt:String id="GroupLabel" DefaultValue="Reflect"/>
    <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Reflect AI"/>
    <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Title" DefaultValue="Open Reflect sidebar"/>
  </bt:ShortStrings>
  <bt:LongStrings>
    <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Reflect AI gives you feedback to ensure your message is as risk-free and respectful as possible - before hitting send."/>
  </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>

    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.5">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox"/>
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url"/>
 
          <!-- Message Compose -->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <Group id="msgComposeCmdGroup">
                <Label resid="GroupLabel"/>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgComposeInsertGist">
                  <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Title"/>
                    <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
                    <SupportsPinning>true</SupportsPinning>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
                
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>

       <bt:Images>
    <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/Alphy_Icon_64x64.png"/>
    <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/Alphy_Icon_64x64.png"/>
    <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/Alphy_Icon_64x64.png"/>
  </bt:Images>
  <bt:Urls>
    <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html"/>
    <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
  </bt:Urls>
  <bt:ShortStrings>
    <bt:String id="GroupLabel" DefaultValue="Reflect"/>
    <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Reflect AI"/>
    <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Title" DefaultValue="Open Reflect sidebar"/>
  </bt:ShortStrings>
  <bt:LongStrings>
    <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Reflect AI gives you feedback to ensure your message is as risk-free and respectful as possible - before hitting send."/>
  </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>



  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```